# how to load driver?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wireless

I want to develop one driver so i have create one service and one .sys file for driver to be display now i do not know how to attach that two file or how to register my driver to windows.
so just tell me the step which i should follow.

Thanks and hoping for positive response.

Answer (score 2):

You can load driver by using StartService API. And you can also use ZwLoadDriver. It's a native API. You can find more information about them in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the driver you write. If it's a device driver it's automatically loaded once the system needs it for the previously defined device classes.

For drivers which don't need devices you need a special driver service. See this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx) example - section "Dynamically Loading and Unloading the Driver"

Answer (score 1):

Basically the most straightforward is using the following apis (in that order). I think it should be pretty straight forward.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323%28v=VS.85%29.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682028%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
```